# How to convert UTF8 string into HTML string in python 2.5 for correct accent displaying?

Tags: python, html, utf-8

My string UFT8, coming from a database (CSV file encoded in UTF8) is displayed like this on a browser with my main.py code: `value ="roulement \u00e0 billes"`

=> how to convert any of such string into HTML entities, such as value="roulement &agrave billes" in order to display correctly as `roulement à billes` with a browser.

I tried to add:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

on the 1st line of my file , and also :

```
 self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html;charset=UTF-8'
```

but it doesn't change anything

=> so, may be another way is to translate it into html entities ? how to ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your changes *are* correct but puzzling – I’m assuming the error is elsewhere. Where is the string stored? In the code? How is it stored there? We need more code. If your code actually ran before you added the `coding` comment then your code doesn’t actually contain UTF-8 strings, otherwise Python would have complained.

Answer (score 9):

First you should make sure `value` is of type unicode and not a string

```
value.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

Should get you the HTML enitites

[Python Unicode Documentation](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html)

```
>>> value = u"roulement \u00e0 billes"
>>> print value
roulement à billes
>>> print value.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
roulement &#224; billes
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I added to my code:

      value = unicode(value)

      value = value.encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace')

and it works perfectly.

Many thanks !
Philippe

Comment: Glad it helped.. Don't forget to check the answer checkbox, will help others with similar problems if it's marked as solved!

Answer (score 1):

To embed unicode string literals in your code:

a) Make sure your source file is in UTF-8 (and add the `# -*- coding` line), then use the literals directly:

```
u'Zażółć gęślą jaźń'
```

b) Escape them in unicode literals:

```
u"roulement \u00e0 billes"
```

In both cases you need to use the `unicode` type, not `str` type, so prefix your literals with `u`.

```
>>> type("kos")
<type 'str'>
>>> type(u"kos")
<type 'unicode'>
```

---

> how to convert any of such string into HTML entities, such as value="roulement &agrave billes" in order to display correctly as roulement à billes with a browser.

You shouldn't need to do this, except those that interfer with HTML itself, like `<` or `>` and a couple more.

Just encode your HTML file as UTF-8 and make sure that the browser will pick the encoding up (the response content type is cool, you can also drop in `<meta charset="UTF-8">` or `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` inside `<head>`. The regional characters should be understood by browsers easily.

Comment: Thanks for your help !
Philippe